# PowerShell Script For Opening URL On Random Time Loop

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I need a Powershell script which will open 3 URLs at a random time. The time between 10 to 15 mins and will run continuously Until killing the task 
Steps are:

```
 powershell.exe -noprofile -command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://your_url"
```

Comment: do you want to catch the response of the URL call or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just need to fire the request and don't care about the response, you can use `Get-Random` and `Start-Sleep` to sleep for a random interval between 10 and 15 minutes:

```bsh
$URLs = @(
  'http://site.tld/url1'
  'http://site.tld/url2'
  'http://site.tld/url3'
)

$minSeconds = 10 * 60
$maxSeconds = 15 * 600

# Loop forever
while($true){
  # Send requests to all 3 urls
  $URLs |ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_
  }

  # Sleep for a random duration between 10 and 15 minutes
  Start-Sleep -Seconds (Get-Random -Min $minSeconds -Max $maxSeconds)
}
```